# Clearing contents of fileUpload control through javascript

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, upload

I am using a script to check the file size of the selected file, Now i want to clears the contents of the file upload ,if the file exceed the size limit:

```
var myFile = document.getElementById('attach');
myFile.addEventListener('change', function () {
 var size = this.files[0].size;
 if(size>10000000){
 showDialog('File exceeded maximum allowed limit of 10 Mb', 'File Size Exceeds');
 clear('new');
}
```

});

And the clear function is:

```
 <script>
  function clear(tagId) {
  document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML = 
  document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML;
  }
 </script>
```

The html input control code is

```
  <div id="new">
  <input type="file" name="attach[]" id="attach" size="30"
  onchange="document.getElementById('moreUploadsLink').style.display = 'block';" />
  </div>
```

The problem is the contents are not cleared, if cleared only for the first time, file size exceeds, if the user changes his selection again and again, the contents are not cleared. Some kind of logics error may be

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to clear contents of div then:

```
myFile.addEventListener('change', function () {
 var size = this.files[0].size;
 if(size>10000000){
   showDialog('File exceeded maximum allowed limit of 10 Mb', 'File Size Exceeds');   
 }
 clear('new'); //place it out of if , if you want to clear everytime
});

function clear(tagId) {
  document.getElementById(tagId).innerHTML = "";
}
```

Did you mean something like this..